# How to add a string of data attributes to react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can I insert a string of data attributes to a react render function in a simple way?

```
  render() {
    let data_attr_str=' data-test="1" data-test-2="2"';

    return (
      <div className="grid" {data_attr_str}>
        WHY YOU NOT WORKING? 
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to de-serialize data and show it with JSX?

Comment: Hey Tiago, I would like the final html output to be:       <div class="grid" data-test="1" data-test-2="2"> WHY YOU NOT WORKING?</div>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSX is not a template engine, so you can't just concatenate that string. I think you should check https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html for more details.

But you can use spread attributes: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes.

```
render() {
  let dataAttrs = {
    'data-test': '1',
    'data-test-2': '2'
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid" {...dataAttrs}>
      NOW IT WORKS
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks fhelwanger , also +1 for the 'NOW IT WORKS!'